# How to update EF models when using DB Code first?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I have added added Entity Framework to my project and selected Code first from database when creating my models. But the problem is, i couln't find how find how to update existing models and add new models to my project when i make changes on database.

Comment: Huh? If you are using "Code First" that is supposed to mean you are writing the code first, then allowing EF to modify the database for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very straightforward. Switch on migrations, change/add you classes, create a migration and update your database. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/01/tutorial-series-updated-for-entity-framework-6-code-first-with-mvc-5.aspx) for example. There are plenty of other sources.

Answer (score 0):

When you change your DB you can run the EF generation again but it will overwrite the existing files so you will lose any changes. If you want to maintain code outside the generated files then you can use partial classes. Or alternatively just code them by hand after the initial auto generation, it's quick once you get used to it! :)